# WebsitePanel Character limit for a website name

Tags: windows-server-2012, websitepanel

I have a server with Windows 2012 Standard edition OS and WebsitePanel 2.0 as hosting control panel. I am hosting and managing hosted websites through WebsitePanel. I have never faced any problem to host any website. But, this time when I host a website with more than 17 characters website name, I am facing a strange problem. When user wants to host the domain from their end, they are receiving character limit error message.

However, when I have hosted that website through serveradmin, I have never encountered any problem. Is there any character limit on user end? How can I resolve it so that users can host the website without any problem from their end?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with adding domain with greater than 17 characters in Website panel 2.0 is resolved in website panel 2.1

Comment: Thank you for your update. Now, I will plan my WebsitePanel upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Client can enter maximum 17 characters to create domain.18th character is not allowed,but from server admin such limitation is not imposed.

Comment: Ok ..As I understood, this is a limitation of WebsitePanel 2.0 from client side. Is there any way to increase this character limit for a website name from clent side?

Comment: Yes, it is limitation of WSP and you donot have any alternative other then add it from ServerAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is limitation of WSP and you donot have any alternative other then add it from ServerAdmin.

Comment: WebsitePanel 2.1 is also released..is this fixed in newer version? so we can upgrade WebsitePanel version...

Comment: I am not sure about fix with WSP 2.1 version